# RegularExpression DataAnnotation testing for patterns in a string

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

I have some requirements for data validation on a field in one of my models in a web service and I feel like Regex is a good fit but I can't seem to compose or find what I'm looking for.

1. The string needs to be 24 alpha numeric characters.
2. At least of 8 of the characters must be Alpha.
3. The last 5 characters of the string must be Numeric.

---

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^[\p{L}8\p{N}.(\d{5}5]+$")] 

 public string VIN { get; set; }
```

Comment: Try `@"^(?=.{24}$)(?=(?:\P{L}*\p{L}){8}).*\d{5}$"`

Comment: The string limit can also be set with `[StringLength(24)]` attribute. Then, the regex will be `[RegularExpression(@"^(?=(?:\P{L}*\p{L}){8}).*\d{5}$")]` or `[RegularExpression(@"^(?=(?:\P{L}*\p{L}){8})[\p{L}\p{N}]*\p{N}{5}$")]`

Comment: If the pattern should work on the client side, too, you need to use something like `[StringLength(24)]` and `[RegularExpression("^(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[a-zA-Z]){8})[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]{5}$")]` (or if you need to use string length inside the pattern, `"^(?=.{24}$)(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[a-zA-Z]){8})[a-zA-Z0-9‌​]*[0-9]{5}$"`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had used the [StringLength(24, MinimumLength = 24, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Length")] for the length.  I wasn't sure if it was better to cover the length under a separate annotation or in the Regex annotation.

Comment: And what about the regex then? Did any of my suggestions worked for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes actually all of them.  You were 100% on point.  I spent some time trying to look at your syntax so I understood better what each part was doing.  The {8} I understood as the min number of alpha characters and [^A-Za-z] means alpha, but I didn't understand why the *[a-zA-Z] or what that was saying same thing for the *[0-9] in the numeric part.  I thought that would have been covered by the [a-zA-Z0-9] part.  I'll give you credit if you make an answer for sure.  If you had the time, I'd love to better understand whats happening here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you know that the string length can be checked outside the regex, so, I will include the string length check into the regex below just for educational purposes.

The main issue was that you actually wrote a pattern that matches 1 or more characters defined inside a `[...]` character class. `^[\p{L}8\p{N}.(\d{5}5]+$` matches the start of the string (`^`), then 1+ chars (either letters (`\p{L}`), `8`, digits (`\p{N}`), `.`, `(`, again digits (but with `\d`), `{`, `5`, `}`, again `5`), and then the end of string (`$`).

You need to use lookaheads to impose restrictions:

```
@"^(?=.{24}$)(?=(?:\P{L}*\p{L}){8}).*\d{5}$" (server side)
@"^(?=.{24}$)(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[a-zA-Z]){8}).*[0-9]{5}$" (client/server side)
```

or - if your string cannot contain arbitrary characters, but just letters and digits:

```
@"^(?=.{24}$)(?=(?:\P{L}*\p{L}){8})[\d\p{L}]*\d{5}$" (server side)
@"^(?=.{24}$)(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[a-zA-Z]){8})[a-zA-Z0-9‌​]*[0-9]{5}$" (client/server side)
```

The difference between server/client side is that the server side accepts a .NET regex and is thus Unicode aware, `\d` can match all Unicode digits, and `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter, while client side only supports ECMAScript regex, and is thus not Unicode aware.

*Details* (let's examine the last server side pattern):

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{24}$)` - the length of the whole line must be 24 chars (note `.` does not match linebreaks)
- `(?=(?:\P{L}*\p{L}){8})` - there must be at least 8 letters preceded with 0+ chars other than letters
- `[\d\p{L}]*`  - 0+ digits or letters, as many as possible, but
- `\d{5}$` - 5 digits (`\d{5}`) must be at the end of the string (`$`).